# C# publish desktop project with database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a school project where I have to build a desktop application in C# with ASP.NET MVC 5.Im using Visual Studio 2015, and Sql Server.

That application contains a small database with about 5 tables and some data. The project is done and it works fine on my computer. My problem is: part of the task is making the program I made work on another computer.

How do I publish my application? Publish with One-Click makes the installer, but, when I do install the software in another computer, it gives an error that it cannot connect to the database. How can I deploy my project WITH the database to another computer?

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1:

After an long search, i found an youtube video that explains how to do a Setup Project using Visual Studio 2015, where you can choose what you need to install and the configurations you need to adjust. I´m still trying to make it work, but i can fell im at the right path finally.

Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zx6w3BDD6Sg

Comment: Are you using visual studio?  You should add a Visual Studio Installer project to your solution.

Comment: What kind of *database*? Any answer would be highly dependent on that detail. Please [edit] your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database are you using?

File-based databases like SQLite or SQL Server Express are built to store their data in easily transportable files that can be shipped along with your app/site.

If you're using a server-based database like SQL Server, MySQL, etc., you'll need to ensure that the target machine/environment has the same database server installed and you'll need to write a deployment script that attaches pre-populated data files to the server. This may be a lot more work.

Comment: Im using SQL server. How do i write that deployment script? i have no clue really. Any good tutorial ?

Comment: Ah. SQL Server proper (i.e. requires installation of SQL Server the product) or SQL Server Express? If the former, note that you'll need to install/access SQL Server on the machine/environment you intend to deploy to. You'll also need admin rights on that server. And the ability to attach database files or restore from a backup, or transfer using DTS. Or BCP if you're masochistic ;) Details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314546

It **MAY** be easier to convert your project to use SQL Server Express or SQLite instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try with using Sqlite as a database with entity framework code first approach with that you can hold the database in user's computer (c:/users/username/appdata). By code first approach you can create the database while the user install the application and you can drop the database while user uninstall the application.